# How to properly pass string to Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a simple function in a static class ChardinHtml.DataIntro(string message). The function is supposed to render something like data-intro='my message' and I want to use it that way:

`<div @ChardinHtml.DataIntro("These are your site's settings")/>`.

(The output would be `<div data-intro="These are your site's settings"/>` )

What exactly should I return?
Is it string/encoded string/MvcHtmlString/MvcHtmlString with encoded string inside? What should I do to protect myself from characters like ( ' ) (apostrophe) inside a message?

The code looks like this:

```
public static string DataIntro(string msg)
{           
    string str = string.Format("data-intro='{0}'", msg);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML helper method to render this. You might return `MvcHtmlString` as the output. Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode the string before you use it

```
public static class MyCustomFancyHtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyFancyAttr(this HtmlHelper helper, string msg)
    {
        msg =  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(msg);
        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("data-intro ='{0}'", msg));
    }
}
```

And you can call it like after including the namespace in the razor view using the `using` statement

```
@usint YourNamespaceWhereYouDefinedTheMethod

<div class="test" @Html.MyFancyAttr("test'ing")> test</div>
```

While this answer your question, I am not sure what your use case is, But **my recommendation is to write the data attribute directly in the razor view** unless you have some complex logic involved in determining what/when to render this.

Comment: Are you sure it works with the ( ' )? I've just tried it and it and got <div data-intro="These are your site" s settings/>

Comment: @user3284063 See my updated answer. that should work fine. I verified.

Comment: I ended up with string str = string.Format("data-intro=\"{0}\"", msg); return MvcHtmlString.Create(str); Anyway, thanks.